# .htaccess is causing 403 on one link only

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Bit of an odd one and I feel it must be answered but I can't seem to find it.

I have the following in my .htaccess file on a custom PHP site **(NOT WORDPRESS)**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(contact|gallery|links)$ $1.php [L]
```

I cannot work out why "gallery" only is giving me a 403.

```
example.com/links
example.com/contact
```

Both work as expected and go to the desired pages. However

```
example.com/gallery
```

Redirects to

```
example.com/gallery/
```

And throws the 403 Forbidden error

gallery.php is a page and can be accessed from the same URL

There's nothing on gallery.php to redirect or check a query string or compare the URI. I cannot understand it.

Really flying blind on .htaccess stuff (always have), so any help greatly appreciated. What am I doing wrong?!

Also, tested it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ and it said my work was correct, so really don't understand what it's finding incorrect. Why does it think gallery is a subfolder, not a URL?

And I have JUST realised, I do actually have a gallery folder, so if anyone can tell me how to use the htaccess to access the page and not the folder, I'd greatly appreciate it! If it helps, there's a .htaccess in the gallery folder to prevent direct access to images:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI 
# AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi

<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g)$">
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Would they be conflicting?

Comment: Do you also have a directory named `Gallery` ? If so, You can use this `DirectorySlash  off` in your htaccess to solve this.

Comment: I literally just edited to say I do. I'm an idiot. So now my issue is, how do I get it to work with the page gallery.php and not go to the directory. I added "DirectorySlash Off" but this hasn't resolved (though it does stop the trailing slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gallery` is a physical directory, you will need to set `DirectorySlash Off` in order to prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash via a 301 external redirect. (This redirect gets cached persistently by the browser, so you will need to clear your browser cache before continuing.)

Note, however, that when disabling the `DirectorySlash`, you must also ensure that `Options -Indexes` is also set to prevent mod_autoindex from generating directory listings when the trailing slash is omitted from a directory, since a `DirectoryIndex` document in that directory will no longer prevent the directory listing being generated. See the [security warning under the `DirectorySlash` directive in the Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

You *may* also need to set [`RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) to allow mod_rewrite to match directories that have no trailing slash.

You then need to modify your existing rule...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
> RewriteRule ^(contact|gallery|links)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

Remove the first two `RewriteCond` directives. They aren't required since you are wanting to rewrite 3 specific URLs. If any of the conditions fail then the rewrite does not occur.

If `contact`, `gallery` or `links` happen to exist as physical files (very unlikely) or directories (`gallery` is a directory it seems) then the rewrite does not occur.

---

#### Summary

```
DirectorySlash Off

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(contact|gallery|links)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was going something stupid...