# My htaccess file to hide php extensions, isn't working for one single page. It adds a trailing slash to that one

Tags: php, .htaccess

I added the htaccess code below to hide php extensions to one of my websites... it works fine, but one page (video.php), it keeps adding a trailing slash, ending up in a 404 error. I tried different iterations like videos.php, videoo.php, video-new.php, etc. All variations work showing me the page without the php extension, but for some reason "video.php" ends up as "mydomain.com/video/" giving me the 404.

Can anyone figure out what is the cause of this, thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is `video` also a directory name?

Comment: yes... ouch.. do you think that's the problem? thanks

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. mod_dir will automatically append the trailing slash with a 301 redirect. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159994/369434) to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159596/htaccess-is-causing-403-on-one-link-only You could alter your existing rule to allow trailing slashes, but you are still going to experience the redirect (unless you follow the procedure in the linked question). It is better to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Thank you MrWhite.... I moved all the video files into a new directory, updated all the references to the old directory and now the video.php page comes up without any issues, no trailing slash. SOLVED. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a directory with the same name as the file of which I wanted to hide the extension. That was creating a conflict. So to anyone who has the same issue, check to make sure your directories don't share the same exact names as your php files. MrWhite solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Is the slash not in the link that takes you to this page?
- Isn't there a cache problem on this page?
- Have you tried forcing the slash to be removed?
  It's a bit barbaric and not very clean but it may help you to eliminate a problem and find the cause.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$ 
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Comment: No the link for all pages don't include the slash because i just wanted clean links for the pages.  But thanks, i will try that code.